# Triangle won't disappear when recoloring canvas - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a simple game in JavaScript using canvas.
One of the classes I made represents a triangle, and it's draw function receives a canvas context and fills a triangle:

```
draw (ctx)
{
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
  ctx.beginPath ();
  ctx.moveTo (this.x, this.y);
  ctx.lineTo (this.x, this.y + this.height);
  if (this.x == 0)
    ctx.lineTo (this.x + this.width, this.y +  this.height / 2);
  else
    ctx.lineTo (this.x - this.width, this.y + this.height / 2);
  ctx.lineTo (this.x, this.y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}
```

The problem is, that at some point, the canvas should be recolored

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect (0, 0, cnvs.width, cnvs.height);
```

but when it does, the triangle doesn't disappear.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear canvas you can do this (it clears your transformations too).

```
canvas.width += 0; // canvas resizes to the same size
```

Another way

```
context.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
```

After clearing you can recolor your canvas.